# I have replaced my hard drive in mac book pro with SSD drive - Can I use that hard drive to replace the optical drive and have 2 disks?

Tags: macbook-pro

If I do the above will the drive need a caddy or will it just slot straight in ?

Answer (score 5):

If you have a unibody (black keyboard) MacBook Pro, then yes, you can totally use the old hard drive to replace the optical drive. In fact, I'm writing this post on a MacBook Pro with that exact set up :)

You'll need a caddy indeed. I'm using an [OptiBay](http://www.mcetech.com/optibay), which works fine. You can find cheaper alternatives on eBay, but I'm not sure how well they fit. However non-unibody (silver keyboard) MacBook Pros use PATA for the optical bay, and thus this won't work unfortunately.

Comment: There may be a big issue with this approach — [potential damage to the hard drive](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/74493/macbook-ssd-replacement-sudden-motion-shock-sensor-in-optical-bay) and your data.

Answer (score 0):

+1 for Kiezpro but cheaper alternatives are available from macsales and from other sellers on amazon. Check those out as well.